Parallelizing efficiently a numerical integration over a list of data
Say I have a function f[x] that is an expensive multidimensional numerical integration. I want to map it over a list and evaluate it for each element. Currently, I am doing
ParallelMap[f[#] &, list]

but it is completely inefficient compared to plain Map. I've read various answers on SE about how mma's parallel utilities can be worst compared to the usual ones, especially when the exchange of data b/w master and slave kernels is large. The problem is that in my case the numerical integration is by far more expensive, so even if there's a cost in data exchange it should be almost negligible.
My question is whether there's another way to parallelize this simple process and inspect the results?

Please try making a simple example which shows the behaviour you are observing, and include it into the question. Also, there may be issues with distributing the definitions. Have you tried DistributeDefinitions[f]?
